# How to get integer value from JTextField of Swing?

Tags: java, swing, integer, jtextfield

How to get integer value from `JTextField` of Swing as we get string value via `getText()` method?

```
try {
        String sql = "insert into employeeinfo   (username,password,obtainmark) values(?,?,?)";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txt_username.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_password.getText());
        pst.setInt(3, txt_obtainmark.getText());
        pst.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data inserted");
    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

I am not able to insert `integer` data type value from the `JTextField`, but able to insert only `string` or `varchar` type data.

Comment: 1) Consider using a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) instead. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `Integer.parseInt(string)` to get Integer value.

```
pst.setInt(Interger.parseInt(txt_obtainmark.getText()));
```

Comment: @Ragataj Don't forget the to catch the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: OP is already catching all `Exception`. So no need to explicitly handle it. It can be done if you want to show a specific error message like enter number input.